# Android Spinner adapting an array with unknown elements

Tags: android

I am building spinners which contain information which I am parsing from a certain document. So I decided to adapt the spinner to an array. If I were to initialize a string array like this:

```
String [] TEST = {"one", "two", "three"} and pass this string here:

ArrayAdapter<String> numAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TEST);
```

Everything works fine. BUT, since I do not necessarily know what will go into the spinner I have a parser (which correctly parses and stores the information in the string array) which causes the program to crash when I pass the array to the ArrayAdapter. I tested it by building a simple string array with a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        test[i] = {"hi"};
    }
```

and it DOESN'T WORK. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Try using an ArrayList<String> instead of a String array.

Comment: What is the length of your string?

Answer (score 0):

No curley braces while assigning value, as well as you need to initiate array with size before using it. Here is example code. But this code will populate "hi" 6 times.

```
String[] test = new String[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        test[i] = "hi";
    }
```

Comment: whoops sorry, idk why I had curly braces in there I didn't in the actual problem. Anyway I found a roundabout way of solving the problem, which essentially requires me to find the size of the information I am parsing before I actually put it into the array.